# 404 when trying to access WCF service

Tags: wcf

I am just getting started with WCF and am having a bit of trouble getting my message encryption to work. I finally got Role based authentication working with Asp.Net Identity 2.0 and am now trying to secure all data exchanged with encryption. I have signed my own x.509 certificate using SelfCert. Now when I try to hit any method on my contract I get a 404. I think the problem might be somewhere in my web.configs. Can anyone point out any **obvious** noobie mistakes in these web.config files?

## Service Config

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="authBehavior">
      <serviceCredentials>
        <serviceCertificate findValue="onpSquad"
                            storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                            storeName="My"
                             x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
        <clientCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="None" />
        </clientCertificate>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"  customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="WCFServiceWebRole1.Onp.Security.IdentityValidator,WCFServiceWebRole1" />
      </serviceCredentials>
      <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="Custom" serviceAuthorizationManagerType="WCFServiceWebRole1.Onp.Security.RoleAuthorizationManager,WCFServiceWebRole1">

      </serviceAuthorization>

    </behavior>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="authBehavior" name="WCFServiceWebRole1.SupportTicketSubmission">
    <endpoint address="SupportTicketSubmission.svc"
              binding="wsHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="MessageAndUserName"
              name="SecuredByTransportEndpoint"
              contract="WCFServiceWebRole1.Onp.IServiceSquadContract" />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="MessageAndUserName">
      <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

## The client

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IServiceSupportTicketSubmission" />
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IServiceLoggingContract" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService1" />
          <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IServiceSquadContract">
            <security mode="Message">
              <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
            </security>
          </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:64054/Service1.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
            name="WSHttpBinding_IService1">
            <identity>
                <userPrincipalName value="MARIASCOMPUTER\chuyita" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:10234/SupportTicketSubmission.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IServiceSupportTicketSubmission"
            contract="OnpService.IServiceSupportTicketSubmission" name="BasicHttpBinding_IServiceSupportTicketSubmission" />
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:10234/SupportTicketSubmission.svc"
           binding="wsHttpBinding"
           bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IServiceSquadContract"
           contract="OnpService.IServiceSquadContract"
           name="SecuredByTransportEndpoint">
        <identity>
          <dns value ="onpSquad" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>

    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

### Old config file

As you can see from below, there were never any explicit endpoints defined. This is the first time I actually have to define them so that I can use ASP.Net's Identity 2.0 for logging in and also setting up encryption.

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

### Update thus far

I got a WCF book and read the first chapter. I've got my binding working correctly and I am able to access the methods of my ISquadContract but now am having issues with Identity 2.0 not grabbing the provided username from the request. That's a topic for another question. Here is what my new config looks like

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<protocolMapping>
  <add scheme="http" binding="wsHttpBinding"/>
</protocolMapping>
<services>
  <service name="WCFServiceWebRole1.SupportTicketSubmission"
            behaviorConfiguration="authBehavior"
            >
    <endpoint address="SupportTicketSubmission.svc"
               binding="wsHttpBinding"
               contract="WCFServiceWebRole1.Onp.IServiceSquadContract"
               bindingConfiguration="squadBindingConfiguration">

    </endpoint>
  <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex"></endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="authBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"  customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="WCFServiceWebRole1.Onp.Security.IdentityValidator,WCFServiceWebRole1" />
      </serviceCredentials>
      <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="Custom" serviceAuthorizationManagerType="WCFServiceWebRole1.Onp.Security.RoleAuthorizationManager,WCFServiceWebRole1">
      </serviceAuthorization>

    </behavior>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="squadBindingConfiguration">
      <security mode="None">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your client configuration** file appears to define config to allow it to connect to three distinct service endpoints, one available at the address:

```
http://localhost:64054/Service1.svc
```

which is expecting to find there a service which exposes a contract called:

```
ServiceReference1.IService1
```

and the other two available at the address:

```
http://localhost:10234/SupportTicketSubmission.svc
```

however, one of these is expecting to call the service contract called:

```
OnpService.IServiceSupportTicketSubmission
```

and the other one is expecting to call the service contract called:

```
OnpService.IServiceSquadContract
```

**Your service configuration** file, on the other hand, defines a service endpoint available at the base service address of:

```
SupportTicketSubmission.svc
```

and exposing the contract:

```
WCFServiceWebRole1.Onp.IServiceSquadContract
```

This is about as confused a picture I think I have ever seen in two WCF config files which are supposed to work together. There are multiple problems here. If you want me to help you detangle this, write me a comment below.

Comment: Tom, I appreciate the help. I'm fumbling around in the dark with this. I have one .svc which exposes 3 contracts on the service. They are `WCFServiceWebRole1.Onp.IserviceSquadContract`, `IServiceSupportTicketSubmission`, and `Logging.IServiceLoggingContract`. They each serve a different purpose. From my understanding you can have multiple contracts but only 1 .svc file hence the reason for having 3 different contracts with 3 different functionalities. On the consumer I clicked on `Add Service Reference` which gave me the namespace `OnpService` and contract `IServiceSquadContract`

Comment: Adrian thanks for the clarification. So currently do you suspect the authorization and certificate stuff is causing the 404? Have you consumed these service endpoints successfully before? It's confusing as your service config only defines a single endpoint. According to your comment, I would expect to see multiple service endpoints defined.

Comment: Yes that does seem confusing. This service is already up and being used for logging and support ticket requests. I am trying to add functionality for police to lookup plates using it. I updated my answer with the old config I had prior to messing around with authentication etc. The process I used to get this thing to work was literally write the contracts, implement them, and deploy the web service to azure. In the client I would simply add a service reference and paste the URL to my .svc which would create the proxy class. I've never had to touch the web config until now.

Comment: P.S. I accidentally edited your response. I was trying to edit my question.